# when the server's child close socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix, client-server

On the concurrent server, server spawns many children(assume that I am using multiple process when clients connet). So, if client close sockets(`close()` function), it sends `FIN` to server and receive `ACK` from the server.

Finally, server's `read()` function returns `0` and `exit()` function is called. It causes server child to terminate and close socket, and send `FIN` to its client.

In this situation, how can server receive `ACK` even though server's child socket is closed? and how can server re-send `FIN` when client doesn't receive the `FIN` even though there is no connected socket because of child which is terminated?

Does kernel keep that terminated process's socket until finishing final four-handshaking although it is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. `close()` is normally asynchronous.

Comment: It means that `close()` doesn't return in the kernel until finishing final handshaking, like file descriptor is not fully closed when one process is opening file although its reference count is zero?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean any of that. 'Asynchronous' means it *does* return before processing is finished, and the FD is closed but the connection lingers on ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `close()` on sockets is normally asynchronous, and sockets can linger after application is terminated. You can easily see them in `netstat` output in their approriate state (for example, `TIME_WAIT` or `FIN_WAIT2`).